# How to make a chat bubble like WhatsApp's chat bubble in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, flutter-layout, whatsapp

I'm going to make a chat bubble like WhatsApp's chat bubble. However, things are not yet done. What I need to do is read an image from a message containing a URL.

URL: https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2022-11-15/russia-expected-to-agree-to-extend-black-sea-grain-export-deal

Expected results:

[image: Expected result]

[image: Expected result]

Actual results:

[image: Actual result]

[image]

My code:

```
Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.75,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.amber,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(15.0),
          topRight: Radius.circular(15.0),
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(0.0),
          bottomRight: Radius.circular(15.0),
        ),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Text(
              name,
              style: const TextStyle(
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 50, 150, 150),
                fontSize: 12.5,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Linkify(
              onOpen: (link) async {
                if (await canLaunchUrl(
                  Uri.parse(link.url),
                )) {
                  await launchUrl(
                      Uri.parse(link.url));
                } else {
                  throw "Could not launch $link";
                }
              },
              text: message,
              style: const TextStyle(
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 50, 150, 150),
                fontSize: 20.0,
              ),
              linkStyle: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20.0,
                color: Colors.blue,
                decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            child: Text(
              timeago.format(sentAt.toDate()),
              style: const TextStyle(
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 50, 150, 150),
                fontSize: 15.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

If you need more info feel free to leave a comment!

How to make a chat bubble like WhatsApp's chat bubble in Flutter? I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you add the news url too? I think it going to get those information from its html tag.

Comment: I think the @OnurKağanAldemir answer is good to start with.

Comment: @eamirho3ein check the comments on his answer

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to detect if there is a URL in the text and preview the URL. You can use the [any_link_preview](https://pub.dev/packages/any_link_preview) package for URL preview.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I tried it before and it showed something like asking I'm a robot. Also, if something like the second and fourth image appears in my question, use words that are not URLs, it returns no results

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TM60E.png

Comment: Just, when I use other URL, it shows text but no image

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSB5f.png

Comment: There is no guarantee that this information will appear on every link. The page to which the URL will redirect is responsible for providing this information. You should also consider this. The document has descriptions that can add placeholders for missing fields.

Comment: Ok, I added placeholders. Only, if something like the 2nd and 4th image appears in my question, which contains words that are not URLs, no results are returned

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the package. I have no idea what's next.

Comment: Also, where to add the placeholders? I added the `placeholderWidget` field, but I still get the same [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSB5f.png)

Comment: Should I open an issue on the package's Github repository?

Comment: Definitely. Maybe they can fix the problem quickly and release a new version.

Comment: I opened an issue: https://github.com/sur950/any_link_preview/issues/40