# Where to add placeholders in any_link_preview package in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using `any_link_preview` package. I follow [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74471700/how-to-make-a-chat-bubble-like-whatsapps-chat-bubble-in-flutter#comment131464272_74471788) and want to add placeholder specifier in any_link_preview package.

However, I added the `placeholderWidget` field, but it doesn't show the placeholder as I expect, as shown in the image below:

[image]

My code:

```
AnyLinkPreview(
  placeholderWidget: const Center(
    child: Icon(
      Icons.image,
    ),
  ),
  link: message,
),
```

If you need more info feel free to leave a comment!

Where to add placeholders in `any_link_preview` package in Flutter? I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: could you add your code too?